# slick slider on transition keep structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am using the slick slider and trying to create a certain design for the actual slider. What I basically need is a structure similar to this:

```
div             div
    div     div
        div
```

I've been able to get this design working hover when in sliding/transition through it automatically goes to this design

```
div div div div div
```

Where it goes back to the original design. I would like to know if its possible to keep the top design as it goes transition. Below is my current CSS, HTML and jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="loop">
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px; }

.test, .slick-active:nth-child(1), .slick-active:nth-child(5) {
    margin-top: 10px; }

.test-2, .slick-active:nth-child(2), .slick-active:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: 40px; }

.center-test, .slick-active:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 70px; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var loop = $(".loop");
loop.slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    sliderPerRow: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true
});
loop.on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    loop.find(".slick-active").first().addClass("test");
    loop.find(".slick-active").last().addClass("test");
    loop.find(".slick-active").eq(1).addClass("test-2");
    loop.find(".slick-active").eq(3).addClass("test-2");
    loop.find(".slick-active").eq(2).addClass("center-test");

});
loop.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    loop.find(".slick-active ").removeClass("test");
    loop.find(".slick-active ").removeClass("test-2");
    loop.find(".slick-active ").removeClass("center-test");

});
loop.find(".slick-active").removeClass("test");
loop.find(".slick-active").first().addClass("test");
loop.find(".slick-active").last().addClass("test");
loop.find(".slick-active").eq(1).addClass("test-2");
loop.find(".slick-active").eq(3).addClass("test-2");
loop.find(".slick-active").eq(2).addClass("center-test");
});
```

I'm guessing instead of margin there should be some sort of offset, where once the code is sliding each div is being calculated. Here is the documentation for slick slider:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

**EDIT**

I've also added in this css rather than adding a margin to the divs.

```
.test, .slick-active:nth-child(1), .slick-active:nth-child(5){
top:10px;
position:relative;
}
.test-2, .slick-active:nth-child(2), .slick-active:nth-child(4){
top:40px;
position:relative;
}
.center-test, .slick-active:nth-child(3){
top:70px;
position:relative;
}
.slick-track{
height:100px;
}
```

So far what I have observed is that it adds the class for the structure change after the slide has finished the transition, hence the 'afterChange' in the JS. But would it be possible to get the structure to be applied when the transition is also in place.

Comment: If margin is not working, try with position. It might be also a matter of the height of whole slider. Maybe you have to set up some minimum height for slides? I'm pretty sure that what you want to achieve is possible: think  about each slides like they are containers for products and position products inside them where you want.

Comment: @miss.emenems sorry that doesn't work as it, seems when you slide or navigate to the next slide it doesnt account for the structure of the css. And then once you land on the appropriate slide it will then add in the .slick-active and which ever test class. So it shows a brief time delay with the carousel.

Comment: not really a solution but maybe it will point you to the right direction http://output.jsbin.com/hiyepa/

Comment: @ionutvmi, wow thats almost there, is there a way to just tweak it from Your Content1 to Your Content2 and that would be almost what ive needed the carousel to do. Theres just a little big of an issue when it goes back to previous slide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious problem here is the infinite looping.
Maybe someone will manage to figure that out one day but for now if you are willing to give that up this should do the trick.
It will work with any number of slides.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $loop = $(".loop");
  
  $loop.slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      sliderPerRow: 1,
      swipeToSlide: true,
      speed: 500,
      infinite: false
  });

});
```

```css
.slick-track{
  height:100px;
}


.loop .product {
  background: #ccc;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  transition: transform .5s; /* same duration as in js */
  transform: translateY(0);
}


.loop .product.slick-current + .product {
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.loop .product.slick-current + .product + .product {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

.loop .product.slick-current + .product + .product + .product {
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.7/slick.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.7/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="loop">
  <div class="product"> Your ContentA </div>
  <div class="product"> Your ContentB </div>
  <div class="product"> Your ContentC </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content1 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content2 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content3 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content4 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content5 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content6 </div>
  <div class="product"> Your Content7 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.product:nth-child(5n+1),
.product:nth-child(5n+5)
{
    top:10px;
    position:relative;
}
.product:nth-child(5n+2),
.product:nth-child(5n+4)
{
    top:40px;
    position:relative;
}
.product:nth-child(5n+3)
{
    top:70px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Slick slider adds elements (`slick-cloned`), thats why you had problem with styling them. Now you don't need all this javascript magic ;)
[Here is nice explanation](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) of `nth-child`.

Watch out using `nth-child` because it not always works as you might think. For example:

```
<style>
    .product:nth-child(1){background:red;}
    .product:nth-child(2){background:blue;}
</style>
<div class="loop">
    <div class="promo"> Some promo </div>
    <div class="product"> Your Content1 </div>
    <div class="product"> Your Content2 </div>
</div>
```

What will be backgrounds of those elements?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think:
slick slider adds and removes elements as you slide or swipe, so the nth-child selector you used won't work well.

try using class name instead nth selector, like:

```
 .test, .slick-active:frstchild{
    top:10px;
    position:relative;
    }

<div class="loop">
      <div class="product frstchild"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product frstchild"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
      <div class="product"> Your Content </div>
    </div>
```

or you can use define cycle size in nth-child selector accordingly, like:

```
.test, .slick-active:frstchild(3n+1){}
```